# pagination for query from table with irregular id

Tags: php, mysql

my table is like:

```
id         code         name
110       qqwe          abhabah
111       qqwe           fgfgfgf
115        dsfsd          sdsdfsdf
```

i want pagination for query `SELECT name FROM 'table' WHERE code='qqwe'`

How do i do this?

Comment: doesn't matter what your query is like. the pagination logic stays the same. there's plenty of examples on this site, so voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `LIMIT`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

```
SELECT name FROM 'table' WHERE code='qqwe' LIMIT 0 10
```

will get the first 10 results starting with result 0

```
SELECT name FROM 'table' WHERE code='qqwe' LIMIT 10 10
```

will get the next 10 results etc..

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  $start = $_GET['page'];
>     $s = ($start - 0);
>     $limit = 6; // No of records to be shown per page.
>     $back = $start - $limit;
>     $next = $start + $limit;
> ```
>
> SELECT name FROM 'table' WHERE code='qqwe' LIMIT $start $limit;

in view

```
<?php
            $num = 1;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i = $i + $limit) {
                if ($i != $start) {
    ?>
                    <a href='<?php echo $category[0]['link'] . ".html" ?>?page=<?php echo $i; ?>'>
       <?php echo $num ?>
                 </a> 
<?php
                } else {
                    echo "<a href='' class='selbull'>$num</a>";
                }
                $num++;
            }
       ?>
```